# React Native input field losing focus after typing character

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input, react-navigation, focus

Every time I type a character into any of my input fields, it will lose focus and I can't continue typing unless I click back into the input field.

Here is my login form. I checked to make sure that state is being updated correctly. It seems like every time the app rerenders it unfocuses but I can't figure out why. I've looked at plenty of examples where it seems like people are doing their forms the same way as me so I'm not sure what's wrong.

App.js

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import { StatusBar as ExpoStatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { LoginScreen } from "./src/screens/LoginScreen";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <LoginScreen />
      <ExpoStatusBar style="auto" />
    </>
  );
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent("meals-to-go", () => App);
```

LoginForm.js:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

export const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  const LoginScreenContainer = styled.View`
    flex: 1;
    flex-direction: "column";
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 50px;
  `;

  return (
    <LoginScreenContainer>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
        value={text}
        placeholder="Insert your text!"
      />
    </LoginScreenContainer>
  );
};
```

I removed basically all the code possible in order to find the source of the problem but I can't find where the problem is. I've checked state and made sure its updating properly. Looked at countless examples of people creating forms in react native and I can't see anything wrong.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I was defining the styled component within my LoginScreen component. Basically, every time my state updated my application would redeclare my styled component causing my nested input field not to focus.

This is the correct way:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { TextInput } from "react-native";
import styled from "styled-components/native";

const LoginScreenContainer = styled.View`
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: "column";
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 50px;
`;

export const LoginScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <LoginScreenContainer>
      <TextInput
        onChangeText={(text) => setText(text)}
        value={text}
        placeholder="Insert your text!"
      />
    </LoginScreenContainer>
  );
};
```